# Getting a MySQL error code 1093: "You can't specify target table 'fdd1' for update in FROM clause" in UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL, I'm trying to do an update with a join on a table and am getting a 1093 error.  This is the code I'm using:

```
UPDATE fdd_test AS fdd1
INNER JOIN  fdd_test  AS fdd2 
ON fdd2.Trade_Date = (
   SELECT MAX(fddsub.Trade_Date)
   FROM fdd_test fddsub
   WHERE fddsub.Trade_Date < fdd1.Trade_Date) 
SET fdd1.Prior_Pct_UpDn_Since_Open = fdd2.Pct_UpDn_Since_Open,
      fdd1.Prior_14_Day_MFI = fdd2.14_Day_MFI
WHERE fdd1.Symbol = 'A' ;
```

I've also tried it using this syntax, but that gives a compile error:

```
UPDATE fdd_test AS fdd1
SET fdd1.Prior_Pct_UpDn_Since_Open = fdd2.Pct_UpDn_Since_Open,
      fdd1.Prior_14_Day_MFI = fdd2.14_Day_MFI
INNER JOIN  fdd_test  AS fdd2 
ON fdd2.Trade_Date = (
   SELECT MAX(fddsub.Trade_Date)
   FROM fdd_test fddsub
   WHERE fddsub.Trade_Date < fdd1.Trade_Date) 
WHERE fdd1.Symbol = 'A' ;
```

You should also take note that the aliases also refer to the same table.  I'm basically trying to update data from one row in the table with data from the row just prior to it (date-wise).

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE fdd_test AS fdd1,  fdd_test  AS fdd2
SET fdd1.Prior_Pct_UpDn_Since_Open = fdd2.Pct_UpDn_Since_Open,
    fdd1.Prior_14_Day_MFI = fdd2.14_Day_MFI
WHERE  fdd2.Trade_Date = (
   SELECT MAX(fddsub.Trade_Date)
   FROM fdd_test fddsub
   WHERE fddsub.Trade_Date < fdd1.Trade_Date) AND fdd1.Symbol = 'A' ;`
```

Comment: jospratik, I'm tried your code verbatim and still get the same error 1093.